# How to set an existing property as a date property in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

I have fields `start_date` and `end_date` on one of my models.

For some time, we have been saving these properties as `Carbon` dates without using the `$dates` property:

```
start_date: {
    date: "2016-09-28 00:00:00.000000",
    timezone_type: NumberLong("1"),
    timezone: "-04:00"
},
end_date: {
    date: "2016-09-30 00:00:00.000000",
    timezone_type: NumberLong("1"),
    timezone: "-04:00"
}
```

I would like to make use of the `$dates` property in Laravel and convert them to `Carbon` dates.

However, Laravel doesn't appreciate when I simply add them to the property:

`protected $dates = ['start_date', 'end_date'];`

And then try to convert them:

```
foreach($models as $model) {
    $model->start_date = new Carbon($model->start_date);
    $model->end_date = new Carbon($model->end_date);
    $model->save();
}
```

As it errors out on the Accesssor:

```
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php"
line: 760
message: "preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you added them to `protected $dates`, they're already Carbon variables; there's no need to call `new Carbon(...)` on them.

Comment: They aren't saved as other `$dates` properties, as they were saved to the model before they were added. Other date properties are saved as: `ISODate("2018-11-15T22:01:01Z")` while mine are saved as an array.

Comment: Not sure I follow; if you're setting `$model->start_date = new Carbon(...);`, then when you save it, it will save a non-Carbon variable to the Database. When you retrieve this model, the date will be a string, unless `start_date` is in `protected $dates`; then it will be a `Carbon` variable.

Comment: I just updated my answer, I think you need a custom accessor if you didn't save your dates as strings the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The `$dates` array is just used to cast a date/datetime string stored in the database to a Carbon instance when you load it. You can't save a Carbon instance to the database directly, you should first call something like `toDateTimeString()` on the Carbon instance and store that string.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

EDIT: I see your comment that you have saved your dates in the database as arrays? You'll probably need to write a custom accessor to convert those into Carbon dates since Carbon only parses strings.

Check out the Laravel documentation on how to write an accessor: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor